# Injecting dependencies in a project using Spring 4.1

Tags: java, spring

I have a project where I shouldn't use `@Autowired` to inject dependencies

We have created our own Context in the project and I do not have access to the `getBean()` method

I have access to Services from Context

In the project I have `DAO` that I want to inject. At the moment I have as `@Autowired` and it works but I need to get through this solution and find other

I am looking for how to inject and use bean be wear `@Autowired` in `Spring 4.1`

This is justified by the fact that `@Autowired` very slow down loading the project as a module to another project

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the statement

> This is justified by the fact that @Autowired very slow down loading the project as a module to another project

Looks very suspicious to me

What can slow down the loading is an inefficient component scanning boundaries defined in your project.
Here is an example:
If you have a project that uses component scanning "com.*" then spring fill try to find beans in all the packages under "com.*" which includes all thirdparties starting with package "com". The same goes for "org.*". So you should define exactly where the beans should be searched.

Now, having said that, in general you can use Java Configuration. Here is an example:

With Autowiring

```
  @Component 
  public class A {}

  @Component 
  public class B {
     @Autowired 
     private A a;
  }
```

With Java Configuration:

```
public class A{}

public class B {
   private final A a;
   public B(A a) {
       this.a = a;
   }
}

@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  @Bean A a() {
    return new A();
  } 

  @Bean B b(A a) {
    return new B(a);
  }
}
```

Both ways are supported in Spring 4.x

Comment: And could you on XML. This is a very large project and in the main Core I can not change too much. I can add news in my module. But the main Core has annotations in classes like Service and Repository but there is also configuration in XML

Comment: I can't define what causes slow loading. The project is too big and done by too many people. The only conclusion we have is that `@Autowired` slows down system

Comment: XML is the oldest way of configuration, it will also work. As for autowired - in order to  understand why the statement is wrong I think the best would be understanding how exactly spring gets started.... Even if you have thousands of beans once they're found it takes a particle of second to autowire them all. Another possible reason is that the beans initialization contains some "slow".